# Multiplexer diagram of \$C = A \cdot B\$

Tags: logic-gates, multiplexer

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to illustrate, as a diagram, a multiplexer. I realise that a multiplexer takes in a number of input signals and depending on the control sign, outputs the selected signal as a single output. In my course a normal Multiplexer looks like the following:

[image]

Before I did anything, I set $$se1 \equiv S$$ and $$out \equiv X$$. Therefore the Boolean expression, for the following will be $$(\neg SI_0)+(SI_1)=X$$. For me that's not the hard part but what if I have the following Boolean expressions and I want to convert it into a Multiplexer diagram:

$$C = A + B$$
$$C = A \cdot B$$

How would I go about doing this? My initial thought was that since the Boolean expression is in the form $$C=(\neg S \cdot A)+(S \cdot B)$$ and the only explanation I could come up with, is that $$S \equiv A$$ therefore the control sign would be **A** and not **S**, therefore the it has the same diagram as the one above but with $$I_0 \equiv A$$ $$I_1 \equiv B$$ $$S \equiv A$$ . But then how could I do that with $$C = A  \cdot B$$

Comment: Some of what you are looking for might already be found [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/256263/how-do-you-implement-the-following-function-using-nothing-but-21-mux/256278#256278) on this site.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by putting 0 in the first input, \$A\$ in the second input, and \$B\$ in the select bit. Hence
$$C = \bar{B} 0 + BA = AB.$$

If you set the first input to \$A\$, the second input to \$B\$, and the select bit to \$\bar{A}\$ you get
$$A + \bar{A}B = A(B + 1) + \bar{A} B = A + AB +\bar{A} B = A + (A + \bar{A}) B = A + B.$$

It should be noted that if you set the select bit to \$A\$, as you have done, you get
$$\bar{A}A + AB = AB,$$
not \$A + B\$.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhM1qr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>